# Does using Thread.Sleep use more of the processor than ManualResetEvent would when a thread waits for signal from another thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I'm using Thread.Sleep for a lower priority thread to wait for a variable to increment before the thread processes; then it loops and awaits same variable again.

If I have very many of the same class of thread, say 1000 instances, would this take substantially more processor cycles compared with using ManualResetEvent instead of Thread.Sleep?

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: The question doesn't seem to make much sense for me. A thread in the waiting state doesn't consume a CPU regardless of how the thread got to this state: by calling `Sleep` or waiting on a handle. What can be different is a frequency the system scheduler checks the awaking events with (in case of `Sleep` it's dictated by period specified as a parameter). So answering `would this take substantially more processor cycles` - it shouldn't make any difference for the scheduler (which is main CPU consumer in that case) as merely implies traversing of threads queue of the same size in both situations.

Comment: How often does scheduler awaken thread during Thread.Sleep() ?

Answer (score 2):

```
while (weAreNotReady) 
{ 
    // nothing here, keep looping
}
WeAreReadyToDoSomething();
```

The above is called [Busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). Pros: You will be notified as soon as possible. Cons: 100% CPU.

```
while (weAreNotReady)
{
   Thread.Sleep(someTime);
}
WeAreReadyDoSomething();
```

The above is called [Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)). Pros: Very little CPU if "someTime" is large enough. Cons: Equivalent to busy waiting if "someTime" is small. Unnecessary delay if "someTime" is high.

ManualResetEvent or some other event-driven option is obviously the best, but sometimes impossible to implement.

So to answer your question: Yes it will take more cycles to do polling compared to an event driven approach. Is it "substantially" more? It depends on how long you sleep().

Comment: What in seconds would be "someTime" small and large?  In my case,  Thread.sleep(n) would be n between .1 and 0.1 seconds.

Comment: I cannot answer that without a context. In some cases polling once per day or once per hour is ok. In other cases polling 10000 times per second is needed. It all depends on a particular situation. Therefore, a timeout like that is usually not hard-coded, but configurable, so it can be modified later when needed.

Comment: Sometimes a little bit of busy waiting can be faster than ManualResetEvent. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/spinwait

Answer (score 1):

In general: with polling (with or without Thread.Sleep), CPU time is wasted because every thread keeps wakes up and using CPU to check the variable. With an event, no CPU time is wasted because the threads do not run *at all* until the event is set.

Exception: If the variable changes *often*, so that threads only need to poll once or twice each time, which means that not much CPU is wasted, then polling can be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks.  I believe this is the answer..... Out of curiosity, how often does a thread on Windows 10 executing Thread.sleep(n)  "wake up" to check the time?